# Wordpress. Not allowing User to publish posts until he is approved by admin after registration

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a plugin or a solution in which new user is able to login after registration but not able to publish posts until he is approved by admin..
I have tried "WP Approve User" plugin but its not doing the job what i want.?
"Only when the user is Approved by Admin" then he is allowed to publish the posts. otherwise not.
Please Help me with this.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/wordpress-plugin-for-post-approval-by-editors   Check this

Answer (score 0):

Try these plugins, may be useful

https://wordpress.org/plugins/approval-workflow

or

http://wordpress.org/plugins/gt-post-approval/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but It doesn't work. the second plugin is the one what I want but its not working.